Trouble setting up the VSCode Extention 'Prettify Symbols Mode' on Windows for Python
Trouble getting PSM set up in python
I am using:

VSCode version: 1.95.2
Operating System: Windows 11
Language: Python 3.11.9

I've added settings to customize symbol prettification in Python, but the settings seem to have no effect. I've tried reloading VSCode and double-checking my configuration, but the symbols do not change.
Can anyone help me identify what I might be missing?
Here is the relevant section of my settings.json file:
"prettifySymbolsMode.substitutions":
  [ {
    "language": "python",
    "substitutions": 
    [
      { "ugly": "\\s?\\*\\*\\s?2",    "pretty": "²",       "post": "\\b" },
      { "ugly": "\\s?\\*\\*\\s?3",    "pretty": "³",       "post": "\\b" },
      { "ugly": "\\*",                "pretty": "·",       "pre": "[^\\*]|^", "post": "\\s|$" },
      { "ugly": "<-",                 "pretty": "←" },
      { "ugly": "->",                 "pretty": "→" },
      { "ugly": ">=",                 "pretty": "≥",       "pre": "[^=\\-<>]|^", "post": "[^=\\-<>]|$" },
      { "ugly": "<=",                 "pretty": "≤",       "pre": "[^=\\-<>]|^", "post": "[^=\\-<>]|$" },
      { "ugly": "==",                 "pretty": "=",       "pre": "[^<>=!]|^", "post": "[^<>=]|$" },
      { "ugly": "!=",                 "pretty": "≠",       "pre": "[^<>=!]|^", "post": "[^<>=]|$" },
      { "ugly": "lambda",             "pretty": "λ",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\b" },
      { "ugly": "math.sqrt",          "pretty": "√",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\(" },\n
      { "ugly": "sum",                "pretty": "∑",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\(" },
      { "ugly": "f",                  "pretty": "ƒ",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "(\"|')" }
    ]
  }
],
"prettifySymbolsMode.adjustCursorMovement": true,
<rest of settings file>

If anything more is required to diagnose the problem, please ask :)
I tried re-installing the plugin, re-installing VSCode and even removed and re-wrote the entire section of the settings.json file which has the settings for the plugin

There is an error : \n
 "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\(" },\n

There should be problems listed in your VS Code.
I installed Prettify Symbols Mode ->  Tested settings.json in workspace or User setting.  Then saved file.
Added >= , and there was no problem.

settings.json:
{
    "prettifySymbolsMode.substitutions":
    [ {
      "language": "python",
      "substitutions": 
      [
        { "ugly": "\\s?\\*\\*\\s?2",    "pretty": "²",       "post": "\\b" },
        { "ugly": "\\s?\\*\\*\\s?3",    "pretty": "³",       "post": "\\b" },
        { "ugly": "\\*",                "pretty": "·",       "pre": "[^\\*]|^", "post": "\\s|$" },
        { "ugly": "<-",                 "pretty": "←" },
        { "ugly": "->",                 "pretty": "→" },
        { "ugly": ">=",                 "pretty": "≥",       "pre": "[^=\\-<>]|^", "post": "[^=\\-<>]|$" },
        { "ugly": "<=",                 "pretty": "≤",       "pre": "[^=\\-<>]|^", "post": "[^=\\-<>]|$" },
        { "ugly": "==",                 "pretty": "=",       "pre": "[^<>=!]|^", "post": "[^<>=]|$" },
        { "ugly": "!=",                 "pretty": "≠",       "pre": "[^<>=!]|^", "post": "[^<>=]|$" },
        { "ugly": "lambda",             "pretty": "λ",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\b" },
        { "ugly": "math.sqrt",          "pretty": "√",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\(" },
        { "ugly": "sum",                "pretty": "∑",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\\(" },
        { "ugly": "f",                  "pretty": "ƒ",       "pre": "\\b", "post": "\"|'" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "prettifySymbolsMode.adjustCursorMovement": true
}


I removed the \n, and it partially worked; some symbols are beeing replaced now, but the replacement of the fString still does not work
Thanks :)

{ "ugly": "f",  "pretty": "ƒ",   "pre": "\\b", "post": "(\"|')" } ,  print(" f'hello world'  ") works for me. The condition requires  ' or ", fString does not meet it.

Somehow, that does absoluteley nothing here, but mainly am i interrested in formating fStrings: print(f"foo{bar}foobar")

Remove ( and ).  { "ugly": "f", "pretty": "ƒ", "pre": "\\b", "post": "\"|'" }

@Programmic Is there any update?
